# How do I remove character limit in opencart reviews?

Tags: opencart

I would like to remove the lower character limit of the reviews in Opencart from 25 to 0 but I cannot find the code that control that.

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the below condition in file `catalog/controller/product/product.php` within the function `public function write()`

```
 if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text']) < 25) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text']) > 1000)) {
```

Replace 25 with 0 or the minimum number of characters needed.

Comment: This worked. Although in the admin you must enable the review and it requires at least one character to save. I just used a space and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

File

> catalog/model/catalog/review.php

line

```
public function getReviewsByProductId($product_id, $start = 0, $limit = 20)
```

AND

In file

> /catalog/controller/product/product.php

line

```
 $this->model_catalog_review->getReviewsByProductId($this->request->get['product_id'], ($page - 1) * 5, 5);
```

Comment: What do these lines do? If I wanted to get rid of the 25 minimum characters what would I do?